# Hacklang tutorial - this type in extend class

Tags: php, facebook, hacklang

What is correct answer for hack tutorial **exercice 16**?
Link to tutorial: [Hacklang tutorial](http://hacklang.org/tutorial/)

My modified code (not marked as solution):

```
<?hh
// The type 'this' always points to the most derived type
class MyBaseClass {
  protected int $count = 0;

  public function add1(): this {
    $this->count += 1;
    return $this;
  }
}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {
  public function print_count(): void { echo $this->count; }
}

function test(): void {
  $x = new MyDerivedClass();
  $x->add1()->print_count();
}
```

I replaced `MyBaseClass` by `this` but still not marked as correct (green text with Exercice number) .. what is correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an engineer working on Hack. I'm pretty sure we have a bug in our completion detection logic for this exercise in the tutorial. Your code looks correct to me -- changing the return type to `this` is, as far as I can see, all you were supposed to do. I'll follow up and get this bug fixed. Sorry about that!

Comment: *poke* I need it to be green @Josh Watzman

Comment: poke again. green is satifaction